# Gradle custom artifact provider repository i.e. custom dependency resolver

Tags: gradle, artifact

All Gradle `ArtifactRepository` implementations do is to provide the source for fetching the artifacts. It can be, for example, plain structure, maven repo and so on. I am aware that I can build my own repository implementation with some custom source.

However, I need something different: to 'hook' inside artifact resolving and fetching. For example, when Gradle is checking if `foo:bar:1.0` is inside of *my* repository implementation, I would like to be able to capture this request and return artifact from wherever I want. (Obviously, its not a static location, otherwise one of the existing repository implementation would be enough).

In other words, when gradle asks for `foo:bar:1.0` I want to control returning of artifacts jars - to have a custom Dependency resolver.

There is an old issue: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1805 that asks for that.

Would this be possible with Gradle?